# how to escape single quote in dynamically created HTML tag content

Tags: javascript

In my javascript code,
I have a variable which have a string. String contains ' or quote in it. Example

```
var name= "hi's";
```

I am creating a link dynamically in a code. where it is written as a string i.e a variable `content` will be used dynamically to create a link on html page.

```
content= '<a onclick="javascript:fun(\'' + name + '\');">'
```

Here it is giving problem that quote in variable `name` completes the string in content. and hence rest portion of content is not recognised..

similar problem arises if `var name = 'hi"s';`
i.e. if double quote is present in it.

plz help

Comment: Don't use inline code => Problem solved!

Comment: How are you using `content` later in the code? Also, links without an `href` attribute is not good practice.

Comment: @Jack : On onload of page i am appending this content to a div.

Comment: @Dolly Then the `'` will be converted to `%27` in the string. That won't help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would create an anchor properly and completely avoid the need to escape anything.

```
var name = "Hi's",
anchor = document.createElement('a');

// should have an href
// links will be displayed differently by some browsers without it
anchor.href = '#';
// using onclick for pragmatic reasons
anchor.onclick = function() {
    fun(name);
    return false;
}
anchor.innerHTML = 'hello world';

// later
mydiv.appendChild(anchor);
```

Btw, the `onclick` attribute shouldn't start with `"javascript:"` at all; that's already implied.

**Update**

If you're still interested in the inline version, variables need two steps of encoding:

1. The first is to serialize the variable properly; I would use `JSON.stringify()` for that
2. The second is HTML escaping; the simplest form is simply to replace double quotes with their proper encoded values.

For example:

```
var content = '<a href="#" onclick="fun(' + 
    JSON.serialize(name).replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + ');">hello</a>';
```